# On the minimal distance of two curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$: existence of a perpendicular to both curves

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

If we are given two curves $x(t)$, $y(t)$ that admit a tangent at each $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\min_{(t, t')\in \mathbb{R}^2} ||x(t)-y(t')||= ||x(t_0)-y(t_0)||$ for some $t_0$ fixed then how do we show that there exists a line that is perpendicular to both curves?

I am pretty sure that one such line (if the curves do not intersect) is exactly the one passing through $x(t_0)$ and $y(t_0)$. I guess that we can start with deriving $f(t) = ||x(t)-y(t)||$ and noticing that $f'(t_0)=0$ but I dont see how to go on from here.

---

Source: A bigger exercice which asks us to deduce that if $||x(t)-y(t)|| \to_{t^2 +t'^2 \to \infty} \infty$ then the minimal distance is achieved and then asks to show that there exists a common perpendicular line to both curves (if both curves have tangents everywhere), but under a modified parametrization we can arrive at the problem which I posed.

We are using the Euclidean norm $||.||= ||.||_2$

Comment: @uniquesolution in that case we can take the line perpendicular to the plane formed by the tangents of both $x$ and $y$ at $t_0$. Anyway, I will re-phrase that in the original text (I meant to say that one such line will always be $x(t_0),y(t_0)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.

Consider the map $$f(u,v)=\Vert x(u)-y(v) \Vert^2$$ If $x,y$ are smooth (i.e. continuously differentiable, then the minimum of $f$ is reached when $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u_0,v_0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(u_0,v_0)=0$$ and $\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u_0,v_0)=2 \langle x^\prime(u_0),x(u_0)-y(v_0) \rangle\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(u_0,v_0)=2 \langle y^\prime(v_0),x(u_0)-y(v_0) \rangle
\end{cases}$

Comment: you beat my by 5 seconds :-|

Answer (score 1):

Note that $||x(t_0)-y(t_0)||^2 $ also minimizes the squared distance. Wlog $t_0 =0$
Now look at $$f(t, s):= ||x(s)-y(t)||^2$$ -- this function atains it's minimum in $(0,0)$, so for $v=(v_1, v_2)$
$$df(0,0)(v) = 2\langle x^\prime(0)v_1- y^\prime(0)v_2, x(0)-y(0) \rangle = 0$$
So the vector $x(0)-y(0)$ is perpendicular to any vector of the form $x^\prime(0)v_1- y^\prime(0)v_2 $ (or the distance is $=0$)

Comment: And reducing the problem to one variable looked as if it would make the problem easier... Damn you math!